# Update type of a field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a index in Elasticsearch, and want to update the type of a field named currentTimeStamp from `long` to `date`, so that Kibana can work on it. Following is my current output of `_mapping` (Other fields have been removed for brevity).

```
{
  "myIndexname": {
    "mappings": {
      "myType": {
        "properties": {
          "currentTimeStamp": {
            "type": "long"
          }
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

When I try to run the following command for updating the type of the column to date type, I get the below mentioned error response. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

`curl -X PUT myIndexname/_mapping/myType` with the following payload

```
{
"myIndexname": {
    "properties": {
        "currentTimeStamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_optional_time || epoch_millis"
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [optimizationframework : {properties={currentTimeStamp={type=date, format=date_optional_time || epoch_millis}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [optimizationframework : {properties={currentTimeStamp={type=date, format=date_optional_time || epoch_millis}}}]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: FWIW elasticsearch does not allow one to update the [type of an existing field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings)

Comment: @keety: So any other alternative to accomplish the same?

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch do you use? In 2.3, they added [reindex api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

Comment: @AshwinTumma The only alternative way is reindexing everything into newIndex/newType which has updated mapping. As Michael said if you are using ES 2.3 then it will be very easy to reindex data otherwise you need to write a program to do that. Hope this helps!